# How can I cycle through my units?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm very early in the game and have 3 scouts running around. In the first few turns of the game it always seemed to remind me to move my scout, but now every turn it just shows the "End Turn" button and I have to manually go hunt down my scouts on the map and remember to move them. This will quickly become unwieldy as I get more units.

Is there a button that lets me cycle through units that haven't acted yet for the turn, or even a list somewhere of all my units?

Answer (score 7):

If you select a unit and then click on the name, it should pop up a list of all your units. The units with grayed names don't have moves, and the units with white names have moves.

<s>Also from what I've read, you can scroll through units if you have one selected by using <kbd>[</kbd> and  <kbd>]</kbd> or  <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and  <kbd>Page Down</kbd> though I have not tested either of these.</s>

Just looked through all the key bindings and tested the keys above, and there doesn't appear to be any way of scrolling through your units with a hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

You cycle through your active, non-sleeping, non-queued-up units with "<" and ">" keys (which are also comma and full stop keys to the right of M key).

Although the problem of the original post's author is probably in something else. Normally the game should either autocycle them for you or provide the "Unit needs orders" button at the bottom right corner, before it switches to "End turn". It's probably an issue of queued up actions, spanning multiple moves, as was mentioned above.